# How to position radio button under the center of image in table cell?

Tags: html, css

I have a form with a radio button and images (example: http://jsfiddle.net/FQbny/), but I want the radio button be under the center of book image - not next to it.

Can you suggest me some solution? Thx!

Comment: For what it's worth, a table isn't the right choice for marking this up: The rows and columns of a table express a relationship - everything in the same column should be related in one way, everything in the same row should be related in another way. Additionally, you should use `<label>` tags for your book images, to make the images clickable, not just the teeny radio buttons. Let me know if you'd be interested in a nicer way of marking this up and I'll post an answer.

Comment: I think you should follow what  Beejamin   said.Table isn't a great choice for marking this up:

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Add the images in one row, then the radio buttons in the next row, rinse and repeat.

On the Radio Button Rows (The < td>
), make it to style to text-align:center;

Something like:

```
<table>
    <tr>
        <td>
            <img src="http://derivativeofln.com/nagrody/howtomeasure.jpg" />
        </td>
        <td>
            <img src="http://derivativeofln.com/nagrody/competingonanalytics.jpg" />
        </td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
        <td style="text-align:center">
            <input type="radio" name="radio-207" value="howtomeasure">
        </td>
        <td style="text-align:center">
            <input type="radio" name="radio-207" value="competingonanalytics">
        </td>
    </tr>
</table>
```

Here's the code working: http://jsfiddle.net/TJGeG/

Answer (score 1):

http://jsfiddle.net/ags4j/

Just change the order (the input after the img) and seperate the two by a `<br>` and give the td an `align="center"`

Answer (score 1):

Hey now change to your html as like this

**HTML**

```
<table>
    <tr>
        <td>
            <div class="parent">
        <input type="radio" name="radio-207" value="howtomeasure" style="botton:0px">
        <img src="http://derivativeofln.com/nagrody/howtomeasure.jpg"  style="top:0px" />
            </div>
        </td>

        <td>
            <div class="parent">
            <input type="radio" name="radio-207" value="competingonanalytics">
            <img src="http://derivativeofln.com/nagrody/competingonanalytics.jpg" />
            </div></td>
    </tr>

<tr>
    <td>
<div class="parent">        <input type="radio" name="radio-207" value="likeablesocial">
        <img src="http://derivativeofln.com/nagrody/likeablesocialmedia.jpg" />
        </div></td>

    <td>
        <div class="parent">
        <input type="radio" name="radio-207" value="oldrules">
        <img src="http://derivativeofln.com/nagrody/oldrules.jpg" />
        </div> </td>
    </tr>
</table>
```

**Css**

```
.parent{
position:relative;
    z-index:2;
}

.parent input{
position:absolute;
    top:50%;
    left:50%;
    z-index:5;
}
```

**live demo** http://jsfiddle.net/FQbny/3/

and now change to `left top` position according to your requirement

Answer (score 1):

Here you go

[**DEMO**](http://jsfiddle.net/FQbny/7/)

Code is below:

```
<table border="0" style="padding:10px;">
    <tr><td><img src="http://derivativeofln.com/nagrody/howtomeasure.jpg"  style="top:0px" /></td><td> <img src="http://derivativeofln.com/nagrody/competingonanalytics.jpg" /></td></tr>
    <tr><td align="center"><input type="radio" name="radio-207" value="howtomeasure" style="botton:0px"> </td><td align="center"><input type="radio" name="radio-207" value="competingonanalytics"> </td></tr>
<tr>
  <td><img src="http://derivativeofln.com/nagrody/likeablesocialmedia.jpg" /> </td>
  <td><img src="http://derivativeofln.com/nagrody/oldrules.jpg" /></td>
</tr>
<tr><td  align="center"><input type="radio" name="radio-207" value="likeablesocial"> </td><td  align="center"><input type="radio" name="radio-207" value="oldrules"></td></tr>
</table>
```

Answer (score 1):

Try this,

```
<table cellspace="0" cellpadding="0" border="0">
    <tr>
        <td>
            <img src="http://derivativeofln.com/nagrody/howtomeasure.jpg" style="top: 0px" />
        </td>
        <td>
            <img src="http://derivativeofln.com/nagrody/competingonanalytics.jpg" />
        </td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
        <td align="center">
            <input type="radio" name="radio-207" value="howtomeasure" style="botton: 0px">
        </td>
        <td align="center">
            <input type="radio" name="radio-207" value="competingonanalytics">
        </td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
        <td>
            <img src="http://derivativeofln.com/nagrody/likeablesocialmedia.jpg" />
        </td>
        <td>
            <img src="http://derivativeofln.com/nagrody/oldrules.jpg" />
        </td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
        <td align="center">
            <input type="radio" name="radio-207" value="likeablesocial">
        </td>
        <td align="center">
            <input type="radio" name="radio-207" value="oldrules">
        </td>
    </tr>
</table>
```